# How to give special permissions to a specific script?

Tags: php, nginx

I have a script `foo.php` which is responsible for manipulating some static files across the system. The problem is that it will work only if I run it using `sudo`, otherwise a insufficient permission error will appear.

This is because those files have CHMOD `644`. Is there a way to set `nginx` or otherwise to use other user (for this delicate matter, preferably root) to execute this specific script?

Comment: After a bit of research, I found this solution to fit the best for my needs. If no other solutions come forward, I will propose this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the script to [execute as owner](http://wanderr.com/jay/linux-run-script-as-a-different-user/2008/05/22/):

```
chmod +s foo.php
```

Comment: This isn't the way PHP scripts are typically executed (unless their CLI). In this case because it's from a web server, owner is just the (low privileged) web process.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup dedicated php-fpm instance with root rights that will serve only your specified script. Put it in chroot and this should working fine.